# The rgb scope of the tricolor in three channel

Tags: css

I want to find the color scope of tricolor,each color has 3 channels(Red,Green,Blue).

for example:

> red between rgb(204, 46, 72)
>
> and rgb(251, 118, 123).

What about the other colors?For example:yellow,green,blue,purple.

Comment: elaborate your question.

Comment: @Rhaegal do you mean the range of main color in rgb?

Comment: Yes,I mean the range of main color in rgb.

Comment: @Rhaegal show my answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try check this out, you can find any color you want

https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp

Answer (score 0):

I found it here:http://www.workwithcolor.com/red-color-hue-range-01.htm
**Yellow:** rgb(255 255 240) to rgb(181 166 66)
**Green:** rgb(178  236 93) to rgb(65   72  51)
**Blue:** rgb(248   248 255 ) to rgb(0  35  102)
**purple:** rgb(191 148 228) to rgb(105 53  156)